# How can I get the data in event mouseover once ,pressing the button alt event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I do by keeping the alt button pressed, I get the data of a tag p in an editable div

at this moment I press the alt button, and I get the data but the mouseover event continues to get the data, and I just need to get it, if I have the button press.

```
function pressAlt(){
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        var keyPressed = e.keyCode;

             if (keyPressed == 18) {//alt button

        $('p').one('mouseover', function() { 
            var txt= $(this).text();
            console.log(txt);

        });
             }
    }
}


<div id='editor' style='' contenteditable="true" class="editor"  onmousedown="pressAlt()"   >   
    <!-- some text of contenteditable div -->
    <p >hi 1</p>
    <p >hi 2</p> 
    <p> hi 3</p>
```

I get the information from the p tag but it does it repeatedly and I need to get it only once per item by pressing the alt button

Comment: Don't use document as your Element. That could fire every time on the entire document. Too many exclusions to write and bad coding practice. Use the specific Element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of your requirement however, this may provide code for you to work with.

I added a second option which is slightly less code.

```js
$('#editor')
  .on('mousedown', function(edtEvent) {
    let et = $(edtEvent.delegateTarget);
    et.on('mouseenter', 'p', function(mevent) {
      let $p = $(this);
      et.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.altKey && !$p.find('button').length) {
          $('<button />').text($p.text()).appendTo($p);
        }
      });
    }).on('mouseleave', 'p', function() {
      et.off('keydown');
    });
  }).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='editor' contenteditable="true" class="editor">
  <!-- some text of contenteditable div -->
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
</div>
```

```js
$('#editor')
  .on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  }).on('mouseenter', 'p', function(e) {
    let $p = $(this);
    $(e.delegateTarget).on('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.altKey && !$p.find('button').length) {
        $('<button />').text($p.text()).appendTo($p);
      }
    });
  }).on('mouseleave', 'p', function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).off('keydown');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='editor' contenteditable="true" class="editor">
  <!-- some text of contenteditable div -->
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution.

```
<script>
        //jquery code
        function pressAlt() {
            $('p').hover(function () {
                var $p = $(this);
                document.onkeydown = function (e) {
                    if (e.altKey) {
                        var texto = $p.text();
                        if ($($p).find('button').length === 0)
                            $($p).append('<button>'+ texto +'</button>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $('#editor button').live('click', function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    </script>


    <div id='editor' contenteditable="true" class="editor" onmousedown='pressAlt()'>
        <!-- some text of contenteditable div -->
        <p>hi 1</p>
        <p>hi 2</p>
        <p> hi 3</p>
        <p> hi 4</p>
        <p> hi 5</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution has some inefficiency and issues to it for example `$($p)` can simply be `$p` as it is already a jQuery object.
`.live` was deprecated and removed in 1.9, and you keep adding event handlers...not good there, you can add an event handler and not do `onmousedown='pressAlt()'`